# My MVC.Controller is losing the Session["user"] value every time I write a log in Http.ApiController

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, session-variables

I have a WebApi project where I also in clude an MVC.Controller to retuns the views.
The problem is when I have to write something in my log file (ApiController), the Session variables are losing their values (I tried cache instead Session but it happens the same thing).

Below is the code I am using:

```
public class Logger
{
 public static void Write(string function, string description)
    {
        try
        {
            var filePath = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "bin\\ReportsLog.txt";
            if (!File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                var swr = File.CreateText(filePath);
                swr.WriteLine(function + ". " + description + " Date: " + DateTime.Now);
                swr.Flush();
                swr.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, true))
                {
                    writer.WriteLine(function + ". " + description + " Date: " + DateTime.Now);
                    writer.Flush();
                    writer.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
    }
}


// ApiController class
public List<Report> Get()
{
  Logger.Write("Get", "Getting report data");
  return Repository.GetReports();
}

//MVC Controller class
public ActionResult Reports()
{
   //Session will always be null if Logger write something before
   if(Session["user"]!=null)
      return View();
   else
      return View("Login");
}

//MVC Controller class
 [System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
 public JsonResult ValidateLogin(string userName, string password)
    {
        try
        {
            RLogin login = new RLogin();
            var validCredentials = login.VerifyLogin(userName, password);
            var url = string.Empty;

            if (validCredentials)
            {
                url = "Routing/Default";
                Session["user"] = login.User;
            }

            return Json(url);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Write("ValidateLogin", ex.Message,ex.StackTrace);
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: where are you setting the session variable user?

Comment: In MVC.Controller, I only have one MVC.Controller that has all the action results to return the views and one method for validate user credentials when login. When user logged in a set the session variable.

Comment: I just edited the code

Comment: Does the user's browser call the Web API? If not, are you relaying the session cookie to Web API from MVC?

Comment: All the calls to the Web API are through ajax and I not use Sessions in Web API, the only place where I use the Session is in the MVC.Controller